Cookie is not getting stored after login
Error occuring in cookie set after deployment
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const createJWT = (res, userId) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "1d",
    sameSite: "none",
  });

  res.cookie("token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development", // Use secure cookies in production
    sameSite: "none", // Prevent CSRF attacks
    maxAge: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 days
  });
};

export default createJWT;

I have encountered an issue where the cookie isn't being set after login in my application. I've tried debugging the server-side code but haven't been able to identify the problem. I've also checked various Stack Overflow answers, but I'm still unsure about what steps to take next. If anyone has experienced a similar issue or has suggestions for further troubleshooting steps, I'd really appreciate the guidance.

Check the node env is set to production, this only occurs when secure is false
